# Show this harmonic function is constant

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to prove the following

> let $\alpha \in (0,1)$. If $u \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is harmonic and $|u(x)| \leq \|x\|^{\alpha}$, Prove the $u$ is constant.

Attempt to prove.

Let's observe that if the problem is true $u$ has to be the constant zero, because $|u(0)| \leq \|0 \|^{\alpha} = 0$, then $u(0)=0$. We can try to use the property that for every $r>0$ (we can do this because $u$ is harmonic in the whole $\mathbb{R^n}$) we have that 
$$ u(x) = \frac{1}{vol(B_r(x))}\int_{B_r(x)} u(y)\,dy $$

and then we can use the triangle inequality and the hypothesis to obtain

\begin{align}
|u(x)| &\leq \frac{1}{vol(B_r(x))}\int_{B_r(x)} |u(y)| \,dy \\
&\leq \frac{1}{vol(B_r(x))}\int_{B_r(x)} \|y\|^{\alpha} \,dy
\end{align}

then I think we can use polar coordinates to try to obtein something that is a constant divided by the radius, then we can make the radius tends to infinity and conclude that $u$ is constant, and for the first part it has to be the constant zero. This is what I think but I don't know how to prove it. Hope you can help me or you can give another idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know the partial derivative bounds?

Take $x \in \mathbb R ^n$. You will have $$\left | \frac{\partial u(x)}{\partial x_i} \right | \le \frac{n \cdot \sup_{ z \in \partial{B_R(x)}} | u(z) |}{R}  $$.

To prove this use the methods illustrated in here [http://www.math.mcgill.ca/gantumur/math566f10/notes/notes1.pdf , Theorem 8]. Basically they prove that partials are also harmonic and use mean value property for them.

Now, $$\frac{n \cdot \sup_{ z \in \partial{B_R(x)}} | u(z) |}{R} \le \frac{n \cdot (||x|| + R)^{\alpha}}{R},$$ by the bound provided by you.

Since $\alpha < 1$, take $R \to \infty$, and you will get that all the partials are zero.

Therefore, the functtion has to be a constant.

Edit: Let $z \in \partial{B_R(x)} $. Then $||z|| \le || z-x|| + ||x|| = R + ||x||$. Since for $ z \in \partial{B_R(x)}, ||z-x|| = R $. Therefore, $|u(z)| \le ||z|| ^{\alpha} \le (||x|| + R)^{\alpha}$.

Comment: I do not understand the last inequality. You said that is for the bound that I provided, but I dont see this is related to your last inequaliy. Thanks

Comment: See edit. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I was thing in the same thing the you post in yout edit, but I wanna make your that I was correct. Again, thank you.

Comment: Looks like you posted the same basic solution I did, over 20 minutes later.

Comment: What's your point?

Comment: Well, really if you are asking me, I'd say that I when I just started writing 2-3 lines of my solutions then your solution came up. I had also spent some time organizing my thoughts, therefore choosing to not write a solution at all appeared to be a waste of time for me. Also, you had not written the solution in detail So I chose to write down the detail and post a solution even if it comes 20 minutes later than yours...

Answer (score 0):

There are Cauchy-type estimates on the derivatives of a harmonic function, just as there are for a holomorphic function. Let's look at $0$ for convenience: There exists a constant $C,$ depending only on the dimension, such that

$$|\nabla u (0)| \le C\sup_{B(0,1)}|u|$$

for all $u$ harmonic in $B(0,1).$ This comes right out of differentiation through the integral sign in the Poisson integral formula. From this we can scale to get

$$|\nabla u (0)| \le C\frac{\sup_{B(0,R)}|u|}{R}$$

for all $u$ harmonic in $B(0,R).$

This result should be useful for your problem.

Comment: but, how to do you use the hypetesis that the problem give you as a inequality?